# How to fail stack when EC2 spot is refused?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using AWS Cloudformation to create EC2 spot instance (with block duration). In order to do this in cloudformation I'm using a Launch Template where spot configuration is set. Then my cloudformation template create an EC2 resource which use the Launch Template.

It work fine except when AWS refuse to create a spot instance. In that case, the cloudformation stack is still running.

I'm wondering if there is a way to fail the stack when the spot request is refused ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `TimeoutDurationMinutes` in your code while requesting for spot instances via cloudformation.

For more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticmapreduce-instancefleetconfig-spotprovisioningspecification.html

Comment: I'm using it (that what I meant by "block duration") but if the request get accepted, everything works as expected. Otherwise the stack stay in "CREATE IN PROGRESS" state and I don't see the spot request in AWS.

Comment: This seems to be a common issue with cloudformation. However, please check step-7 in https://noise.getoto.net/tag/cloudformation/page/2/
This should be helpful in fixing your issue.